# Write data back to my backend server from a packaged Sencha-Touch 2 App

Tags: php, ajax, jsonp, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to write a Sencha Touch application that I can package in PhoneGap for iOS, Android etc...
The app allows you to input some data which I would like to save to my backend server using PHP/MySQL. It all works when I use an AJAX proxy as I am testing the app on the same server as my database.

However when I package it for mobile devices I run into the same-domain restrictions of AJAX calls. So I modified it to use the JSONP proxy and I can read the data from the server database but have no idea how to write records back. Do I need to somehow pass the data in the GET request? Obviously the server side PHP needs to be different because of the callbacks and the fact JSONP is forced to used GET requests. I am also trying to get CORS working but currently no success.

So my question is how would I implement writing data back to my backend server from a packaged mobile Sencha app running on a mobile device? Either using JSONP if that is even possible or any other alternatives are welcome?

Many Thanks…

Comment: Why not a RESTful Web Service?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting same-domain restriction after packaging the app? I have used AJAX proxy and packaged my app for iPad and it is working fine.